# Upload to Dropbox not working from Laravel with Dropbox driver

Tags: laravel, filesystems, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload a (DomPDF generated) PDF file to Dropbox with the Dropbox driver in Laravel 8. I've installed spatie/flysystem-dropbox and created a DropboxServiceProvider.php with following contents:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Spatie\Dropbox\Client;
use Spatie\FlysystemDropbox\DropboxAdapter;

class DropboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('dropbox', function ($app, $config) {
            $client = new Client([$config['key'], $config['secret']]);
            return new Filesystem(new DropboxAdapter($client));
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The service provider is also added to my config/app providers:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\DropboxServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

In my config/filesystems I've added the dropbox driver (dropbox app key and secret are also set in .env file):

```
        'dropbox' => [
            'driver' => 'dropbox',
            'key' => env('DROPBOX_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('DROPBOX_APP_SECRET'),
        ]
```

Now, when I try to run the following code, it returns false and the file doesn't appear in my Dropbox. When I change the disk to 'local', the file gets uploaded to my local storage.

```
    $path = "pdf/file.pdf";
    $storage_path = Storage::path($path);
    $contents = file_get_contents($storage_path);
    $upload = Storage::disk('dropbox')->put($path, $contents);
    return $upload;
```

I've already tried clearing my config by running `php artisan config:clear`. After trying many different things, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: it says it is supposed to be using an authorization token not an API key and secret

Comment: I already tried that aswell, and gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in the code, but in the permissions in my dropbox app: files.content.write wasn't enabled yet.

[image]